# Any online petition platform that will deliver signatures to target only?

Tags: privacy, petition

Do you know of a platform for online petitions that has the option to deliver signature information to designated target only?

AFAIK, in my home country, people who sign petitions to government must also add the national ID number ("cédula") and contact information (street or electronic address) for the signature to be considered officially valid. (I'm still trying to know the rules on this).

I, originator of this petition, have no need to know the names, cédulas or addresses of the people who sign. However, the government official who will receive the petition, should get a serious looking one. (Let us assume that I don't need to be concerned about pranksters signing the petition).

Do you know platforms that would work for this?

Added: @easymoden00b, there is a question of lack of trust. I want the users to be confident that their personal information will not be misused -- not even by me. That is one reason to use a website that appears trustful, and not a DIY website.

Added: @indigochild, some people may agree with the petition, but not trust the person who collects the signatures (me). I don't need to know the names & address of the people who support the petition. This petition is of interest to people with some money. In my country, people with money do not want to be identified by name and address by the general public, for good reasons (fear of being kidnapped, etc).

Comment: create your own platform.

Comment: Why is it a problem for you to receive this information also?

Comment: Do you mean something like change.org?